# eigenvalues of given matrix $A$ and $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1-i\\ -1-i & i \end{bmatrix} \qquad \text{ and }\qquad B=A^T\ \overline{A}.$$
Then

(A) an eigenvalue of $B$ is purely imaginary

(B) an eigenvalue of $A$ is zero

(C) all eigenvalues of $B$ are real

(D) $A$ has a non-zero real eigenvalue

**My attempt:**

i calculated matrix B it comes to be $$B= \begin{pmatrix} 2&i-1 \\ 2i&-2 \\  \end{pmatrix}$$
also option (B) cannot be true. since determinant of A is not zero.
after this,i am stuck here, i need to pick one out of above options. plz suggest. thanks.

Comment: Assuming B is right, can you set up the characteristic equation?

Comment: option B cannot be true. since determinant of A is not zero

Comment: That's correct, but it is still possible to calculate the char equation: $(2-t)(-2-t)-(2i)(-i-1)=0$ It's a great quadratic problem with complex terms...

Comment: which then is correct choice according to u?

Comment: Your matrix $B$ is not correct.

Comment: Notice that B is hermitian. What property does it have?

Comment: @KittyL corrected matrix B.all eigen values of hermetitian matrix are real.  so option C is right?

Comment: Matrix $B$ is still not correct, but your answer is right.

Answer (score 0):

let me write $A = C + iD$ where $C = \pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}, D = \pmatrix{0&-1\\-1&1}.$ we observe that $C$ is skew symmetric and $D$ is symmetric. now, let us compute  $$\bar A = C - iD, A^T = -C+ iD, B = A^T\bar A = -(C-iD)^2, \bar B^T = B. \tag 1$$  suppose $\lambda = a + ib$ is an eigenvalue of $A.$ from the relations in $(1),$  we can see that $a - ib, -a + ib, -(a-ib)^2$ are eigenvalues of $\bar A, A^T$ and $B.$  we also know that $B$ has real eigenvalues. therefore $(a-ib)^2$ is real. that means $a-ib$ is purely imaginary and $a = 0.$ we have shown that the eigenvalues of $A$ are purely imaginary.

p.s. i computed the eigenvalues of $A$ directly and they are $-i$ and $2i.$